# NextJS Shallow Routing on Dynamic Routes doesn't work

Tags: next.js

If I have a `/posts` folder in NextJS with a `index.js` and `[id].js` file, then this shallow routing will work in the `index.js` file:

```
router.push("/posts", "/posts/" + id, {shallow: true})
```

BUT if I instead have a `/dynamic-posts` folder containing no index.js but e.g. a `[category].js` file and no [id].js but instead `/post/[id].js` then this shallow routing doesn't work:

```
router.push("/dynamic-post/" + something, "/dynamic-posts/post/" + id, {shallow: true})
```

Does anyone know how to fix it? I need a dynamic page for SEO to rank on cities for a webportal similar to Zillow. E.g: https://www.zillow.com/san-francisco-ca/rent-houses/

---

I made a demo of my issue on Stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-ezyusx?file=pages/index.js

Comment: Shallow routing wouldn't work on your `/dynamic-posts/category` route since next considers that a different page than the `/dynamic-posts/post`. As mentioned in the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/shallow-routing#caveats)

Comment: If you want to shallow route, just pass the updated url in the `router.push` first argument and pass the second argument as undefined like `router.push("/dynamic-post/" + something, undefined, {shallow: true})`

Comment: @mtshaikh Thanks for the reply! Yea maybe that's just how it is. I've just detailed what I'm looking to do in my reply here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/40256#discussioncomment-3568719

Maybe you have an idea of how to achive that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, I can just use `window.history.pushState()` instead of using the Nextjs router.

Then I can cosmetically change the URL without causing any redirects or refreshes